# Approximating $C$ functions with polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the space $X = C([0;1])$ of continous real-valued functions with the usual maximum norm.

So the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem says, that every $u \in X$ can be approximated by polynomials $p_n$, such that:
$\forall \epsilon>0 :\exists \ p_n: sup_{x \in [0;1]} |p_n(x)-u(x)| < \epsilon$

Let's for example consider the function $u(x) = e^{-1/x} \text{ for } x \in (0;1], u(0) = 0.$
One can show that $u$ is in $X$ and also in $C^\infty([0;1])$.

My question is:
Let $p_n$ be polynomials and $p_n \rightarrow u$ in X.
Is there any way to figure out how the coefficients of $p_n$ look like?
Usually for $C^{\infty}$ functions you would try to do a taylor series, but in the case of $u$ you would just get $p_n = 0$ because the derivative $u^{(n)}(0) = 0 \ \forall n  \in \mathbb{N}$.

Also i wonder how you would approximate for example $v(x) = |x-\frac{1}{2}|$?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weierstrass approximation theorem only says that there are polynomials $p_n$. There are many possible choices for the $p_n$.

There is a constructive proof of the theorem that uses [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions).

For analytic functions the Taylor series also works.